# Equivalent of Debug.Assert for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, debugging

I'm adapting a large number of SQL Server 2005 scripts to merge two of our databases together. The scripts are run from a .cmd file which calls sqlcmd to run the scripts in order. However, I'm experiencing one or two issues where the scripts are failing.

I'd like a quick way to get a look at the state of some of the scripts where they go wrong - check variable values, the results of some queries, stuff like that.

If I was having this problem with a .NET assembly, I'd augment the code with Debug.Assert or set breakpoints where I knew failures were going to occur, which would pause program execution and allow me to check out variable values.

I was wondering, is there an equivalent in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never managed to make the integrated debugging work well with SQL Server - I usually resort to "printf" debugging, using either [PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) or [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) statements. RAISERROR can do some basic argument formatting, to spit the values out to the messages window. E.g. if you have a parameter @Val1, of type int, you can do:

```
RAISERROR('Val1 = %i',10,1,@Val1) WITH NOWAIT
```

(the WITH NOWAIT option causes the message to appear immediately, rather than the usual SQL behaviour of buffering messages/outputs)

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
-- Assert procedure equivalent to other languages.
-- raiserror() will cause sql execution to stop and throw execep in C# code that is running this statement.
-- Usage:
-- declare @shouldBeTrue bit
-- set @shouldBeTrue = case when 1=0 then 1 else 0 end
-- exec _AT3Assert @shouldBeTrue, 'failed'
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = '_AT3Assert' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE')
 EXEC ('DROP PROCEDURE dbo._AT3Assert')
 GO
create procedure dbo._AT3Assert
    @shouldBeTrue bit,      
    @errorMsg nvarchar (max)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    if @shouldBeTrue is null or @shouldBeTrue <> 1
    begin
        raiserror (@errorMsg, -- Message text.
               11, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
    end
GO
```

Comment: Why wrap the DROP in an EXEC?

Answer (score 0):

I use batch files and check the error code like this:-

```
SQLCMD.EXE -b -l 30 -E -S <SERVER> -i "<SQLFILE>.sql">>"%LOG_FILE%"2>&1

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO. Failed.
) ELSE (
    ECHO. Succeeded.
)
```